# Is there Android NDK support on Cloudbees?

Tags: android, android-ndk, continuous-integration, cloudbees

Part of my build script requires that I run ndk-build, which apparently isn't on the PATH on the Cloudbees box because it chokes on the command. Does Cloudbees have the NDK installed somewhere I can point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short term solution could be to upload http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html linux tar.gz in your private repository on cloudbees and add a pre-build step to expand it from /private/ to /tmp.

Comment: Or even easier, just download from Google in a build step.

Comment: There's a blog post about that: [Continuous Integration for Mobile Apps with Jenkins: A Note on Android NDK Builds](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/12/continuous-integration-for-mobile-apps.html)